# Amazon EC2 instance in Ansible Tower

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I have created one Ansible tower AMI "ami-e606418c" on AWS EC2. How can I see it on my actual Ansible Tower UI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Ansible Tower Documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/quickinstall/install_script.html#run-the-installation-script), which is linked to from the [Tower Trial page](http://www.ansible.com/tower-trial):

> Once setup is complete, you can use your web browser to access the Tower server and view the Tower login screen. Your Tower server is accessible from port 80 (http://tower.company.com/).

Comment: I thing, I am using trial version of Ansible and it is now expired. Hence, I was not able to communicate with the HTTP server currently.

Comment: @MahelaRanawat You should still be able to access the UI even if your trial has expired. Find the public ip address from the amazon ec2 web UI and type that into your browser.

Comment: @chrism: I started running ansible tower with the public IP address from amazon EC2 web UI. The problem is, when I started to run the simple playbook on this host, it tells me the SSH error,permission denied. I have added all the AWS credentials and SSH private key as well. What could be the possible problem ?

Comment: Make sure the username corresponds to the ec2 Ami expected user name. Are you able to connect manually from your machines command line?